# How to loop countdown timer multiple times

Tags: java, android, timer

I am having a problem repeating countdown timer multiple times,in my case 12 times. I have made two countdown timers,one for roundtime and one for pause and works great.Problem is when the pause is finihed I want that roundtime countdown starts again automaticly until 12 rounds with pause are finished.
I use for loop.Is there any better way?

Here is code: when user clicks the button countdown starts

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            long roundtime= Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(msg1))*1000;//user has picked roundtime
            Counting timer = new Counting(roundtime, 100);//class Counting extends CountdownTimer
            for(int i=0;i<12;i++){
                timer.start(); // It goes just ones!
            }




        }
```

And countdown timer:

```
         class Counting extends CountDownTimer {

             public Counting(long roundtime, long countDownInterval) {
                 super(roundtime, countDownInterval);
             }
             @Override
             public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                 textView.setText("" + String.format("%02d:%02d",
                         TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(
                                 TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished)),
                         TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(
                                 TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));
             }
             @Override
             public void onFinish() {  // When roundtime is finished,start pause time!
                 int seconds = msg1 % 60;
                 int minutes = (msg1 / 60) % 60;
                 textView.setText(String.format("%02d : %02d", minutes, seconds));
                 long pause= Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(msg2))*1000; //user has picked pause time
                 Counting2 timer2 = new Counting2(pause, 100);
                 timer2.start();
             }
         }
        class Counting2 extends CountDownTimer {

            public Counting2(long pause, long countDownInterval) {
                super(pause, countDownInterval);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                textView2.setText("" + String.format("%02d:%02d",
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(
                                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished)),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(
                                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                int seconds = msg2 % 60;
                int minutes = (msg2 / 60) % 60;
                textView2.setText(String.format("%02d : %02d", minutes, seconds));
            }
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: have you looked a Handler? It may provide a simpler implementation.

Comment: mjstam,no I did not.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you want it to loop 12 times.
This isn't the issue at hand, however, you'll thank me when it only loops 11 times.

it should be

```
 for(int i=0;i<=12;i++){
            timer.start(); // It goes just ones!
        }
```

As I do not know the implementation of `Counting2`, it appears to be getting hung up on the start function there. I do not know if it's overridden or not. If you have a similar `onFinish` method, this is due to a recursive call back on the original `Counting timer`. Because of this, it loops with a waiting period in between (It doesn't get a stack overflow 'as quickly' as a result).

Comment: DarmaniLink, this is how Counting2 class looks like.I have edit it above. What do you sugest?

Comment: What's with the parenthesis after a right facing curly bracket? I don't see it closing anything.

Comment: Also, I'm guessing CountDownTimer is an abstract class, so there aren't really any 'possible' errors there. Really, what I would do would just have it print out and random points with an identifier of sorts, such as print("Reached1");, "reached2", et cetera so you can pinpoint where it gets hung up. Basically before loops and method calls as well as at the start of those.

Comment: I am sorry,dont get it.You mean at the end? Yea,there is one more } at end of code. Or?

Comment: I see that now... Try adding markers in the code and tell me where it gets stuck. Right before, and if it continues to be stuck after entry.

Answer (score 0):

Try **busy waiting** for the previous timer to finish and then start it again, and it'll do so 12 times.

```
for(int i=0;i<12;i++){
            while(!previousTimerActive);
            timer.start(); 
            previousTimerActive = true;
        }
```

And in your `Counting2`'s `onFinish()` set the indicator `previousTimerActive = false;`. Now you just need to see what way you want this `boolean previousTimerActive` to be 'global' (so it can be accessed from both your activity and your class `Counting2`). You can get it and set it in the SharedPreferences or use a third-party tool like [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) to send it's value from one to the other.